# What is the recommended practice for storing user credentials in Java?

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, spring-security

As a .net developer, I am playing around with java for learning purposes.

I am trying to develop some REST web services and I would like to secure them.
In.net I use token-based authentication, I guess similar to **OAuth1**.

In .net, there are many libraries to use and it is recommended not to store user credentials oneself. So I was able to implement the following class & interface: **OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider** & **IAuthenticationTokenProvider**.
This takes care of salting, hashing, authenticating the tokens, token expirations etc.

What is the industry standard or recommended practice for storing credentials and user tokens in java? I've found apache shiro and spring security, but what I've found is either user info stored inside in files or hard-coded usernames and passwords.

Ideally, I would like to use hibernate for DB work. 
And I'm trying to find out what is the best/recommended way to store user credentials and user tokens etc.

I am trying not to "roll my own", as that is always not recommended. But at the same time, I want to use the correct encryption and hashing standards that have not been broken already.

Comment: In .NET for example there is a UserManager base class that I can inherit from and then I need to override a couple of methods and properties and it will handle storage, password encryption, salting, etc for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend Spring Security. It is highly pluggable and you can implement whatever level of security that is needed.

The users can be persisted in a database. It is common practice. This tutorial explains the basics:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database

It is also good practice to encrypt the passwords. You can implement any encryption you want. You may have to install the Oracle Java Encryption extension.

And you even can add 2-factor login etc...

You really need to read more about Spring Security. Here is the reference:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start.
But what i am really looking for is something more production ready.
In .net for example there are classes that handle storing the user, password, salt, etc  and doing the encryption and all of that.
With the Spring stuff, it seems I have create functions to do it.
I'm just thinking there might be some community/spring/oracle classes or projects out there where most of this has been done already.
As you mention this is quite common, so it doesn't make sense for me to redo all of that.

Comment: i found some classes that looks like they are what i'm looking for in the Spring Security project.
Thanks.